# Working with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have defined a BroadcastReceiver in my activity in the following way to get results from an IntentService running on another thread:

```
receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            boolean isSyncCompleted = intent.getBooleanExtra("issynccompleted", false);
            if (isSyncCompleted){
                showAlert("Sync completed in service");
            }
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }
    };
    //register receiver for service
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ContentSyncService.SERVICE_INTENT_FILTER));
```

Note that I am unregistering my receiver in the onReceive code block and not in onPause. That is because I want to have the receiver listening even when the activity has been destroyed.

But I keep getting the error: "*Activity ... has leaked IntentReceiver ... that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?*"

Comment: what does show alert do? If your activity is destroyed, you can't show anything in its UI...

Comment: check that your broadcast is originally unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me, I override the Activity methods, not a BrodcastReceiver:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // unregister receiver
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // register receiver
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("your.package.name"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only will unregister receiver if you receive action at least one time.
So you need unregister your receiver in OnPause (and in other place if you need), because there you are safe that always will unregister the receiver.

Comment: That is what I want actually i.e. my receiver should be unregistered only if I receive the response in onReceive. Not before that. Reason behind that is I have a long running service which is connected to my activity through this receiver. The activity starts the service and then stays idle for a long time. By the time the service sends the broadcast back to the activity, the activity is already destroyed (by the screensaver). If i unregister the receiver in onPause or onDestroy, the activity is not able to act upon the response from the service.

Comment: Understood. So, I believe that you need use other way to do it. Are you think in register your receiver/unregister on your service? And when you receive the action you send other BroadCastReceiver that your activity will catch it. Now, This BroadCastReceiver that you sent will be register in OnStart and unregister in onPause. I don't know if this the best way, but I believe that works. Sorry if I got it wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Intead of use context.unregisterReceiver(receiver) inside your receiver,

Try it:
activity.unregisterReceiver(this);